# A Hebrew presentation's title is pushed almost entirely off the slide when beamer's Madrid theme is used

Tags: beamer, titles, babel, hebrew, themes

The following LaTeX document was saved at `~/test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
%\babelprovide[main, import]{hebrew}
%\babelfont{sf}{FreeSans}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\title{Title}
\date{2022}
\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Then the following command was executed in the Terminal:

> lualatex ~/test

Consequently, the file `~/test.pdf` was created. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displayed as follows.

[image: Presentation in English]

I then uncommented the three commented lines to set the presentation's language to Hebrew. When I now ran `lualatex ~/test`, the file `~/test.pdf` was recreated. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file now displayed as follows.

[image: Presentation in Hebrew]

Note that Hebrew is a right-to-left language, so the reverse order of the items in the bottom of the slide is correct. But why is the title off-kilter? How can I fix this?

Comment: Use `\documentclass{beamer-rl}`.

Comment: @JavierBezos Thank you. This solves the issue.

Comment: @JavierBezos I’ve promoted your comment to a CW answer. If you’d rather get the karma, I’ll remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to Use

```
\documentclass{beamer-rl}
```